# User Crontab + Python + Random wallpapers = Not working?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, gnome, gconf

I have a python script that correctly sets the desktop wallpaper via gconf to a random picture in a given folder.

I then have the following entry in my crontab

`* *  *   *   *     python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py`

And syslog correctly reports execution

```
Apr 26 14:11:01 bolster-desktop CRON[9751]: (bolster) CMD (python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py)
Apr 26 14:12:01 bolster-desktop CRON[9836]: (bolster) CMD (python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py)
Apr 26 14:13:01 bolster-desktop CRON[9860]: (bolster) CMD (python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py)
Apr 26 14:14:01 bolster-desktop CRON[9905]: (bolster) CMD (python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py)
Apr 26 14:15:01 bolster-desktop CRON[9948]: (bolster) CMD (python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py)
Apr 26 14:16:01 bolster-desktop CRON[9983]: (bolster) CMD (python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py)
```

But no desktopy changey, Any ideas?

Comment: Does you see the value change in gconf-editor? Does the wallpaper change if you set the value from gconf-editor?

Comment: yes and yes, as i said, the script works outside of cron calling as just ~/bin/change-background.py and python ~/bin/change-background.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script depends on the `DISPLAY` environment variable, which is set when you execute the script from the shell in an X session, but unset when the script is run from cron.

Comment: Please state your answer in the form of an answer :)

Comment: @Andrew I though I did.  Your question was "Any ideas?", I gave you the most probable reason given the limited information that you've presented.  I've correctly guessed that the problem is not with cron or gconf, it is with a particular environment variable.  Seeing that you're apparently fluent with *NIX and Python, I didn't feel the need to teach you how to set environment variables (for the record, it's `os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ...` in Python).

Answer (score 2):

As per Bolo's observation, I forgot about building in the DISPLAY into either the script or the crontab.

Easiest solution is to prepend the crontab with `env DISPLAY=:0.0`

so:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 python /home/bolster/bin/change-background.py
```

Comment: Errr, unless some comment was deleted: *his*, not *this*, so no need to wait 44 hours? (But well, that's [a discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47906/etiquette-for-dealing-with-hint-answers).)

Comment: No, sorry, I think you miss understand, or i was not clear enough, I'm waiting for the community to decide; whichever has more upvotes by the time i *could* accept my own answer, will be accepted. Its only fair.

Answer (score 2):

To set the DISPLAY environment variable, I would put it directly in the crontab. Also, I would make the script executable and give it a proper header (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) so that it can be executed directly. Additionally, you can rely on the PWD being set to HOME when the crontab runs.

My crontab would look like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
* * * * * bin/change-background.py
```

You can also set the PATH (in the same manner as DISPLAY) so that the `bin/` is not even needed.

---

The main gotcha for setting environment in the crontab is that values are *not* variable-interpolated. For example, this not give the expected results:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Script is executable, has proper header, and Path is correctly set ( I have alot of things in ~/bin) but I just like explicit stating of whats going on, so having the 'export DISPLAY:0.0' inline in the crontab will remind me why its there in 6 months time :D 
Thank you for your interest.